# How to add a dimension to a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

I have an array that is size (214, 144). I need it to be (214,144,1) is there a way to do this easily in Python? Basically the dimensions are supposed to be (Days, Times, Stations). Since I only have 1 station's data that dimension would be a 1. However if I could also make the code flexible enough work for say 2 stations that would be great (e.g. changing the dimension size from (428,288) to (214,144,2)) that would be great!

Comment: Changing from shape `(428, 288)` to `(214, 144, 2)` doesn't make sense: you're halving the total number of elements there. Did you want something like `(428, 144, 2)` instead?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant! Sorry! 428,144,2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 6)
>>> a.reshape((2, 6, 1))
array([[[ 1],
        [ 2],
        [ 3],
        [ 4],
        [ 5],
        [ 6]],

       [[ 7],
        [ 8],
        [ 9],
        [10],
        [11],
        [12]]])
>>> _.shape
(2, 6, 1)
```

Besides changing the shape from `(x, y)` to `(x, y, 1)`, you could use `(x, y/n, n)` as well, but you may want to specify the column order depending on the input:

```
>>> a.reshape((2, 3, 2))
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]])
>>> a.reshape((2, 3, 2), order='F')
array([[[ 1,  4],
        [ 2,  5],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[ 7, 10],
        [ 8, 11],
        [ 9, 12]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** To add a dimension to an array `a` of arbitrary dimensionality:

```
b = numpy.reshape (a, list (numpy.shape (a)) + [1])
```

**Explanation:**

You get the shape of `a`, turn it into a list, concatenate `1` to that list, and use that list as the new shape in a `reshape` operation.

**2)** To specify subdivisions of the dimensions, and have the size of the last dimension calculated automatically, use `-1` for the size of the last dimension. e.g.:

```
b = numpy.reshape(a, [numpy.size(a,0)/2, numpy.size(a,1)/2, -1])
```

The shape of `b` in this case will be `[214,144,4]`.

---

(obviously you could combine the two approaches if necessary):

```
b = numpy.reshape (a, numpy.append (numpy.array (numpy.shape (a))/2, -1))
```

Comment: `np.expand_dims(a, -1)` does this kind of `reshape`, adding a new axis at the end with the `-1` parameter.  No new functionality, but the newish `np.stack` uses it to concatenate arrays on any new axis.