# add a dummy dimension for a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There has a nd array `A` with shape `[100,255,255,3]`, which correspond to 100 255*255 images.  I would like to iterate this multi-dimensional array, and each iteration I get one image. This is what I do, `A1 = A[i,:,:,:]` The resulting `A1` has shape `[255,255,3]`. However, i would like to enforce it have the shape `[1,255,255,3]`. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a dimension to a numpy array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428496/how-to-add-a-dimension-to-a-numpy-array-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.newaxis` on your resulting array.

Very simple example on a 2d array:

```
x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
x.shape
#: (2, 2)
x[np.newaxis]
#: array([[[0, 1],
#:         [2, 3]]])
x[np.newaxis].shape
#: (1, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.reshape(A1, (1, 255, 255, 3))
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Sure, no problem.  Use 'reshape'.  Assuming A1 is a numpy array

A1 = A1.reshape([1,255,255,3])

This will reshape your matrix.

If A1 isn't a numpy array then use

A1 = numpy.array(A1).reshape([1,255,255,3])

Answer (score 0):

The answer is out... here is an example, notice that you have to look carefully at the brackets to discern whether a and b differ by their dimensions

```
>>> a = np.arange(2*2*2*2).reshape(2,2,2,2)
>>> a.ndim
4
>>> b = a.reshape((1,)+a.shape)
>>> b.ndim
5
>>> a
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]]])
>>> b
array([[[[[ 0,  1],
          [ 2,  3]],

         [[ 4,  5],
          [ 6,  7]]],


        [[[ 8,  9],
          [10, 11]],

         [[12, 13],
          [14, 15]]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If using:

```
for a in A: # iteration on the first dimension
   a = a[None,...]   # add the dim back
   # or a.reshape(...)
```

but if using

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    a = A[[i]]    # preserve the 1st dim
    # or a = A[None,i,...]
```

But I like to use `enumerate` so:

```
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    a = a[None,...]
```

But I'd encourage you to think about why you need that initial 1 dimension.  Maybe you don't even need to iterate?